# Heatmap positions square

Tags: r, heatmap

I have created a heatmap using the heatmap.2 function is R. I would like my individual positions to be square, now some how the positions seems to be rectangular, is there any way to make the positions squared?

My R code is as below and the heatmap image is attached.

```
 > library(gplots)
 > file=read.table("Heatfile_Av_Av.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
 > file[is.na(file)]<-0
 > data_matrix<-as.matrix(file)
 > heatmap.2(data_matrix, scale="none",dendrogram="none", col=grey(seq(1,0,-0.01)),      
 +           trace="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, main="PB2 VS PB1")
```

[image]

Comment: `heatmap.2` uses `layout`, so you can pass it `asp = 1`, which will "work", but mess up your labels and key and such. I think your two options are to create an edited version (`heatmap.3`?) where you put `asp = 1` into the part that plots the heatmap (and you'll probably have to adjust the margins too), or you fiddle with the size of your graphics device until things look pretty square.

Comment: `?heatmap.2` says the `...` parameters are passed to `image` and its help page says that `asp` is among the parameters recognized.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat yes, `asp` can be passed that way, but if you just try it with the `mtcars` example at the bottom of `?heatmap.2` it doesn't really produce desirable output.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not wedded to the `heatmap.2(...)` function, you can do this relatively easily in `ggplot`, and the result is much more easily customized.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(1)
x    <- paste("X",1:30,sep="-")
y    <- paste("Y",1:30,sep="-")
df   <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
df$z <- rpois(length(x)*length(y),12)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x,y,fill=z))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(9,"Greys"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90,vjust=.2, hjust=0))+
  labs(title="PB2 vs PB1", x="",y="")+
  coord_fixed()
```